# Additional crawl space support footings

Tags: crawlspace, support, footings

I have a 92 year old 1 story house in Michigan that is sagging along the main support. I have to add additional support and jack it up in some spots. I'm not even sure that the original piers have footings. it stays reasonably warm in the winter. What type of footings would you use and how deep.

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to answer, and it may depend on the nuances of local code. Seek advice from your inspection office or a local expert.

Answer (score 2):

Your local building department will have the best advice.

They know the ground conditions and possible frost levels and the weight/supports needed for your building.

We can only guess what you actually need.

The size of the footing depend on how much the ground can support per square foot.